# I'm trying to create a website for reserving tickets. I need to add as many passengers as needed using one single form. How is that possible?

Tags: python, html, flask

```
`@views.route('/flight.html',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def flight():
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        global no_of_passenger
        no_of_passengers = request.form.get('no_of_passengers')`
```

In the above view, I'm getting the passenger count from an earlier html page which I'm using later. I need to get the input from the user as many times as the no_of_passengers.

```
`@views.route('/passengers.html',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def passenger():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template('passengers.html')
    return render_template('passengers.html')

@views.route('/passengersinfo.html',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def passenger_information():
    passengercount = no_of_passengers
    passengercount = int(passengercount)
    print(passengercount)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in range(0,passengercount):
            passenger_info = {}
            passenger_info['passengername'] = request.form.get('Passenger_Name')
            passenger_info['Street'] = request.form.get('Street')
            passenger_info['City'] = request.form.get('City')
            passenger_info['State'] = request.form.get('State')
            passenger_info['ZipCode'] = request.form.get('ZipCode')
            return redirect(url_for("views.passenger"))
    return render_template('passengersinfo.html')`
```

In this view I'm trying to run the form as per the user input using a for loop.

The below attached code is the HTML form which is used to get the user form data.

```
`{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block title %}Passenger Information Page{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<form id="Form1" action = 'passengersinfo.html'  method = 'POST'>
    <div>
    <label for ='Passenger_Name' >Passenger Name</label>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'Passenger_Name' id='Passenger_Name' id="Form1">
    
    <br>
    <label for ='Street' >Street</label>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'Street' id='Street' id="Form1">

    <br>
    <label for ='City' >City</label>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'City' id='City' id="Form1">

    <br>
    <label for ='State' >State</label>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'State' id='State' id="Form1">

    <br>
    <label for ='Zip' >Zip Code</label>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'Zip' id='Zip' id="Form1">
    </div>
    <button type = 'submit' id="Form1" >Next</button>
</form>

{%endblock%}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to implement your requirements is to use [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/).
Using a `FieldList` and a `FormField`, it is possible to create a list of a predefined form.
In this way you create a form for your address details and, depending on the required number, you duplicate this. In addition, you can validate the entries made.

If you only want to display one nested form at a time, you can use JavaScript to navigate forward or back.

The following example uses the session to avoid using global variables and stay as close to your defaults as possible.

###### Flask

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    redirect, 
    render_template, 
    request, 
    session, 
    url_for
)
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm, Form
from wtforms import (
    FieldList, 
    FormField, 
    IntegerField, 
    StringField, 
    SubmitField
)
from wtforms.validators import (
    InputRequired, 
    NumberRange
)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

class PassengersForm(FlaskForm):
    passenger_count = IntegerField('Ticket Count', 
        validators=[NumberRange(min=1)]
    )
    submit = SubmitField('Next')

class PassengerForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name', 
        validators=[InputRequired()]
    )
    street = StringField('Street/No')
    city = StringField('City')
    state = StringField('State')
    zipcode = StringField('Zip')

class PassengerDetailsForm(FlaskForm):
    passengers = FieldList(FormField(PassengerForm))
    submit = SubmitField()

@app.route('/passengers', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def passengers():
    form = PassengersForm(request.form, data={'passenger_count': 1})
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['count'] = form.passenger_count.data
        return redirect(url_for('.passengers_info'))
    return render_template('passengers.html', **locals())

@app.route('/passengers-info', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def passengers_info():
    form = PassengerDetailsForm(request.form)
    form.passengers.min_entries = max(1, int(session.get('count', 1)))
    while len(form.passengers.entries) < form.passengers.min_entries:
        form.passengers.append_entry()
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for passenger in form.passengers.data:
            print(passenger)
        return redirect(url_for('.passengers'))

    return render_template('passengers_info.html', **locals())
```

###### HTML (./templates/passengers.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Passengers</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div>
            {{ form.passenger_count.label() }}
            {{ form.passenger_count() }}
            {% if form.passenger_count.errors -%}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.passenger_count.errors -%}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor -%}
            </ul>
            {% endif -%}
        </div>
        {{ form.submit }}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

###### HTML (./templates/passengers_info.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Passenger Informations</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .step {
            display: none;
        }
        .step.active {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {% for subform in form.passengers -%}
        <div class="step {%if loop.first %}active{% endif %}" id="step-{{loop.index0}}">
            {% for field in subform -%}
            <div>
                {{ field.label() }}
                {{ field() }}
                {% if field.errors -%}
                <ul>
                    {% for error in field.errors -%}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                    {% endfor -%}
                </ul>
                {% endif -%}
            </div>
            {% endfor -%}

            {%if not loop.first %}
            <button type="button" class="btn-prev">Prev</button>
            {% endif %}
            {%if not loop.last %}
            <button type="button" class="btn-next">Next</button>
            {% else %}
            {{ form.submit() }}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endfor -%}
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            let step = 0;

            const btns_next = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-next');
            btns_next.forEach(btn => {
                btn.addEventListener('click', evt => {
                    [`step-${step}`, `step-${++step}`].forEach(sel => {
                        const elem = document.getElementById(sel); 
                        elem && elem.classList.toggle('active');
                    });
                });
            });

            const btns_prev = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-prev');
            btns_prev.forEach(btn => {
                btn.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
                    [`step-${step}`, `step-${--step}`].forEach(sel => {
                        const elem = document.getElementById(sel); 
                        elem && elem.classList.toggle('active');
                    });
                });
            });

        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```